# DB Index not being called

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle11g, oracle10g, database-performance

I know this question has been asked more than once here. But I am not able to resolve my issue so posting it again for help.

I have a table called Transaction in Oracle database (11g) with 2.7 million records. There is a not-null `varchar2(20)` (`txn_id`) column which contains numeric values. This is not the primary key of the table, and most of the values are unique. By most of the values I mean there are cases where one value can be there 3-4 times in the table.

If I perform a simple query of select based on `TXN_ID` it take about 5 seconds or more to return the result.

```
Select * from Transaction t where t.txn_id = 245643
```

I have an index created on this column, but when I check the explain plan for above query, it is using full table scan. This query is being used many times in the application which is making the application slow.

Can you please provide some help what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Posting the query plan (including the access and filter predicates) would be helpful.  If the column is a `varchar2`, why are you comparing it against a number rather than a string?  What happens if your predicate is `t.txn_id = '245643'` instead?  Is your application actually using literals (I sure hope not)?  If it is using bind variables, is it binding a numeric value or a string value?

Comment: Can you post the index definition?  Is txn_id the only column in the index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing a `varchar` column with  a numeric literal (`245643`). This forces Oracle to convert one side of the equality, and off hand, it seems as though it's choosing the "wrong" side. Instead of having to guess how Oracle will handle this conversion, use a character literal:

```
SELECT * FROM Transaction t WHERE t.txn_id = '245643'
```

Comment: I see your point. I tested it and the index is being used when I compare varchar on both sides. I will check why application call is taking so long. might be similar issue there. Thanks. I am accepting your answer :)